# Predict the starting and end point from a sequence of points

Tags: math, authentication, geometry

I have a sequence of points ( not vertices's ) which makes a open shape but they are randomly arranged in a array, but to effectively recognize the shape what I need to do is to arrange the points in order the shape was made.

Is there any way in which I can recognize which is the start and end point?

**Edit:** The points are in a 2D plane and I have the boundingbox. The points are obtained from a image processing algorithm which gives me the points from top to bottom (not in the order shape was made) as the image is processed pixel by pixel.

Comment: Don't get it; you have a array with random data and from that you would like to extract the original start- and end point? What kind of info about the shape do you have? Boundingbox?

Comment: hm, I'm thinking from the tags and description you're thinking of a 2D array of touch points like the Android login. Can you provide some more information about the problem? That sort of information would usually be stored, i'd think, rather than guessed. But if i had to guess, only the start has only an outbound line and only the end has only an inbound

Comment: The points are in a 2D plane and yes i have the boundingbox . The points are obtained from a image processing algorithm which gives me the points from top to bottom (not in the order shape was made) as the image is processed pixel by pixel .

Comment: You say you have an open shape and you want the end points of the starting and ending line segments, but if all you have is a list of unordered points, then you don't have an open shape, and there is no start and end.  For a simple example, the points for this shape "[" are the exact same as the points for this shape "]", and both have the exact same points as a closed rectangle.

Comment: How are you computing the outline points from pixels ? Maybe the image processing algorithms also stores a sorted list of points (for example OpenCV's countour finder returns an ordered list of points).

Comment: @PDaddy I understand, but there must be a way by which i can find out the starting and the end points for example, the points that are not starting and end point must have neighbors on both side which are very near to them and the starting and end point will have only one such neighbor . But this algorithm has some obvious flaws .

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza i am not using OpenCV , i am getting this list from a database . what i have is only unordered list of point .It should be interesting to look at how OpenCV does it .

Comment: @rajat an interesting problem then. You have 1) an unordered list of points. 2) No directional connectors from point to point and 3) would like to determine a specific shape they make? Am I understanding that correctly? Mathematically impossible, but I think probabilistic techniques may serve you in this case. What is the general problem environment environment? Determining an android login pattern? recreating a kid's connect-the-dots?

Comment: Ah, I see.  When you said "points", I assumed vertices.  But what you really have are pixels.  So what you need is something like a line tracing algorithm.

Comment: @AK4749 the problem environment is , a child making shapes on paper and i want to detect that shape , without the help of any library .

Comment: @PDaddy yes, that was also my misunderstanding. OK much better. Do you have a specific subset of shapes you'd like to work with?

Comment: yes the characters from A-Z .

Comment: @PDaddy doesn't the line tracing algorithm work on a ordered list of points .

Comment: rajat, you said it yourself: you can get an approximate ordering of points based on proximity.

Comment: and i said that , that approach has many flaws for example if the starting point is near to some point from the shape or starting point is very near to the end point .

Answer (score 2):

Given a set of points, there are various ways to reconstruct a shape from them. If you only take the distance between two points into account, then this basically boils down to a classical [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem): you're looking for a tour through all points which minimizes the length of said tour. You could add one mor atrificial point which has the same distance to all points in the plane. That would turn a cyclic tour into a linear one: the point after that artificial point would be the starting point, and the point just before it would be the end point. There might be TSP approximation algorithms out there which can do non-cyclic tours out of the box.

Only considering distance ignores any inertia inherent to the motion of the painting device. So I don't claim that this is the best possible model. But for most models, I would still think about a way to determine the order all the points, which automatically results in identifying the start and end point. I can't think of a way to reliably identify these two without a way to order all points in between as well.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and i want to order the points in between as well . Are there already implementations of Traveling salesman problem in C++ ?

Comment: I have 128 nodes , is it a good idea to solve it by brute-force ?

Comment: @rajat: Others have [asked for an implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194621/1468366) before. If by “brute force” you mean “try all possible orders”, then compute the number of these orders (128!) and you'll see that this is not an option.

Comment: Yup it seems like it is not a solution . Anything else that you can think of instead of TSP ?

Comment: Wikipedia has [a section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms) on exact algorithms which are more efficient than brute force and still yield exact results. I'm not sure how useful approximations are in your case, but if they are, you might [exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP) the fact that you're dealing with points in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Seems like you want to implement image segmentation instead:

[Paper](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/web/Teaching/Lectures/WS10_11/asr/segmentation.pdf)

Scroll down to page 28 for the mathematical description. This will give you the contours. Does that get you to where you want to be?

---

What you are trying to do is implement

[OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

without the use of an external library. I wouldn't recommend it for production purposes, but think it would be a great problem to tackle.

My suggestion would be to build a simple Artificial Neural Network with the image surface providing the input signals. A feed-forward, backpropagation ANN is quite easy to code, but extremely tricky to get the results you want.

You are, after all, tackling a problem that has no perfect solution yet despite many attempts. I wish you the best of luck and please keep us updated with your progress!

Comment: Ohk , Thanks but from this question what i want is not a Algorithm for the OCR and the main reason OCR does not work is that the points are not detected correctly . I have a ideal setup in which i can detect the points correct , i just want to order the point like they do with contours in OpenCV.

Comment: @rajat got it, in that case if you'd like to implement your own segmentation algorithm, see the above edit and scroll down to the image segmentation section

Comment: Thanks , It seems like that is what i want to do . will let you know after i read it thoroughly .